# unable to patch using kustomize for the resources deployed using helm

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kustomize

I have deployment ingress-nginx using helm

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx-external ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx-external --create-namespace \
  --version v4.4.0
```

As a next step I am trying to patch the deployment using patchesStrategicMerge

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-external-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx-external
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: controller
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-external-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx-external
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-external-controller
            - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
            # - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
            - --ingress-class-by-name=true
```

but I am getting the below error

```
Error: no matches for Id Deployment.v1.apps/ingress-nginx-external-controller.ingress-nginx-external; failed to find unique target for patch Deployment.v1.apps/ingress-nginx-external-controller.ingress-nginx-external
```

Comment: Try doing helm template command (substitute 'upgrade' with 'template') and identify if you actually have resource with that name or is it named differently.